# Tetrahedral change reference system

Tags: geometry

Point P location is referenced to ABCD tetrahedron vertices, let us say (a,b,c,d) coordinates respectively.

**Tetrahedron example**
[image]

I choose an arbitrary point in AB edge (let us call it E) and I want to change point P from previous reference to the ECD triangle reference (e,c',d'). I understand that c and d coordinates remain the same under the new reference (c=c' and d=d'), but I have no idea how to translate a and b coordinates to new e coordinate...

Thank you for your help!